# react-select: Do we need CSS as well just to display a normal select list?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have following code which displays a normal select list. It is working fine logically and i am able to log when any change happens. But the problem is, very small box is being displayed instead of a text box which is adequate to show the options.And my placeholder is being displayed as a normal text. But when i click on placeholder, all values are being displayed.

```
import Select from 'react-select;

class SelectList extends Component {

     onChange() {
       console.log("Value Changed");
     }  

     render() {
         var Select = require('react-select');
         var options = [
                 { value: 'one', label: 'India' },
                 { value: 'two', label: 'Singapore' },
                 { value: 'three', label: 'IceLand' }
          ];

       return(
          <Select
             name="Select List"
             value="one"
             options={options}
             onChange={this.onChange.this(bind}}
          />
       );
}
```

do I need any CSS things here. Could anybody let me know what am I missing here?

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA4hT.png
```

Comment: Will be nice to see a fiddle or a sandbox.

Comment: @Andrew---Sorry, I didn't understand your point.Could you tell me a bit clearly!

Comment: this is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new). It will be more understandable if you show your problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already importing **Select** at the top, why are you doing

> var Select = require('react-select');

again in the render function?

Also your onChange handler should be onChange={this.onChange} and you can bind the handler at the top in the constructor like this:

```
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
```

Or you can pass it to the Select component like this

```
onChange={() => {this.onChange()}}
```

As for the CSS issue, from github:

> // Be sure to include styles at some point, probably during your bootstrapping

```
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```

Comment: --I agree with your points. But could you let me know why am I unable to display the select list with adequate length to show the options?

Comment: I believe it's the issue i mentioned above, you have to include the corresponding CSS.

Comment: ---I got an error when i included this statement as if it is not found. Do i need any files for my project directory?

Comment: Can you post the error here? The css is taken from node_modules, so the full path is **node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.css**

Comment: Andreai--I have an image which shows my output. Please have a look at it once

Comment: Sorry, the image doesn't really say anything except for maybe the fact that you don't have the css included.

Comment: You are right. It's working fine now. Thank you for your time.